# UI Widget testing using loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

UI widget using LoadRunner

I am using HTML/HTTP capture the application transaction for one of my business process. I have to validate the widget loading time explicitly  in one of my business process. Need suggestion as I don't see HTTP mode is not capturing the whole widget.

Comment: What you want to do is to use HTTP protocol to create the load and another TruClient script to capture the widget response time.

Comment: Please define "Whole Widget" and the piece not captured